# php error but where is it?

Tags: php, html

OK Dreamweaver and my local host server keeping saying that their is a error but i have no idea where please help?

This is a php script to figure out if the user already has a account and then  if he doesn't it registers him into the database

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {color:white;font-size:20px;}
.toppa {width: 100%;background-color:#2D2D2D;}
</style>

<?php
//Database Information

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "a8423624_grubber";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$username = $_POST['username'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];    
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$repassword = md5($_POST['repassword']);

$month = $_POST['month'];  
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];  

$Intro = 1;
$admin = "no";

if (!(empty($username) or empty($email) or empty($password) or empty($repassword))) 
{
//a Text field is empty
    if ($password == $repassword) {
     $checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");  
     $checkuser1 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'"); 
     $email_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser1);
     $username_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser);
              // checks email 
            if ($username_exist  > 0)
                      {
                      echo "<div class='toppa' align='center'>
                      <h1 align='Left'> Grubber </h1>
                      </div>
                      <p> You'r Name has been taken please try another Name. </P>";
                      include 'tryagain.html';
                      }
                     else
                      { 
                             if ($email_exist > 0)
                             {
                              echo "<div class='toppa' align='center'>
                              <h1 align='Left'> Grubber </h1>
                              </div>
                              <p> You'r Email has been taken please try another Email.</P>";
                              include 'tryagain.html';
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                $themes = ("http://grubber.host56.com/Themes/Grubber.gif");
                                $date = ("$year/$month/$day");
                                $proimg = ("http://grubber.host56.com/images/defaultprof.png");
                                $query = "INSERT INTO users (admin,themes,proimg,Birthday,Intro,email, username, password)
                                VALUES('$admin','$themes','$proimg','$date', '$Intro', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
                                mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                                mysql_close();
                                echo "<div class='toppa' align='center'>
                                <h1 align='Left'> Grubber </h1>
                                </div>
                                <p> Please sign in to test that your account works </P>";
                                include 'tryagain.html';
                                }

             else
            {
            echo "<div class='toppa' align='center'>
            <h1 align='Left'> Grubber </h1>
            </div>
            <p>You'r passwords are not the same please try again.</P>";
            }

}
else
{
     echo "<div class='toppa' align='center'>
                      <h1 align='Left'> Grubber </h1>
                      </div>
                      <p> Please fill in all fields </P>";
                      include 'tryagain.html';
}
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling `display_errors` and investigating what's going on?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error? When does it happen, does it shop a message? Runtime error?

Comment: So it just says error, doesnt give any clues as to where?

Comment: On your development server you should display all php errors. See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I don't use Dreamweaver but I can't believe it'll report that "there's an error" without further details. I presume you've discarded the error message because you don't think it has any relevance. Please don't: error messages exist for a very good reason.

Comment: I only use Dreamweaver to see if I have any errors with my php script. the error was a syntax error that's what Dreamweaver says but it my local server says t_else so yer. But I fixed it by shuffling around some of the coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should enable `error_reporting`.
Secondly, you should sanitize your input using `mysql_real_escape_string` (else harmful people could [SQL inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and thirdly you should use `or die (mysql_error());` after your SQL queries, like this:

```
$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());  
$checkuser1 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

If your SQL query fails, you will see the proper error.